# which is the right way to use a typescript project inside other project with git submodules and avoid type check errors?

Tags: typescript, git-submodules, tsconfig

What are the best practices for using one Typescript project within another?

Hi, I currently have a (core) project with components that I want to be able to reuse in other (sample) projects, both projects use typescript.

My first approach was to place this core library as a submodule at the level of my project, something like this:

```
sample
|--src/
|------file_using_core_ts
|--core
```

This causes problems because I can't use components declared in core directly, because this shows that **core is outside the root folder**, which is **src**

So I tried to test moving **core** to inside **src**, this works fine in principle, I can run the project (yarn dev) and everything looks perfect, except that it generates problems with tsc and I can't do the build.

In a simplification of the project, it would be something like this:

```
sample
|--src/
|------core/
|----------src/
|-------------sample.ts
|-------------a.ts
|------file_using_core_ts
```

**sample.ts** uses **a.ts**, but **does not import it in a relative way**, but uses *src/a*, which is problematic because tsc thinks the path refers to *sample/src* and not *sample/src/core/src*.

simplified example

```
./src/core/src/sample.ts
Type error: Cannot find module 'src/a' or its corresponding type declarations.

> 5 | import a from 'src/a'
```

I can't change the core imports to use relative paths, my option might be to change some typescript settings or change the location of my module.

I tried to exclude `core` from the typechecking, in the sample project tsconfig I put

```
"exclude: [
    "node_modules",
    "src/core"
  ]
```

I have tried different variants of "src/core/*. , /core, etc....but none of them work, I understand that in this situation even if you exclude the folder, tsc is forced to check the typing.

I'd like to know if there is a better approach to achieve this or if there is a way to configure typechecking, because after all the project runs and works fine when running *yarn run dev*, it's just a type checking problem.

Please, if you have a more descriptive title for the question, suggest it in the comments and I'll be happy to change it.

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want instead of submodules is make core a private (npm or other registry) package and consume it in your projects.
Alternatively have a look at the `workspaces` configuration for `package.json`. this allows you to declare multiple packages and cross reference them.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces